# Using react-redux connect method in react-navigation show error "The component for route 'x' must be a React component

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

I am using react-redux to connect redux to my react-native project, but when I use `export default connect(state => ({ count: state.count }))(Test)`
 method and importing to react navigation as `creactStackNavigator({test:Test})` it shows

```
The component for route 'test' must be a React component

import MyScreen from './MyScreen';
...
test: MyScreen,
}
```

but when I remove `connect()` method it works perfectly fine

**Environment:**

```
"react":16.8.4
"react-native":0.59.4
"react-redux": "7.0.2",
"redux": "4.0.1",
"react-navigation": "2.18.2",
```

**Test.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View,Button} from 'react-native';
import  {connect}  from 'react-redux';

class Test extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>count:{this.props.count}</Text>
         <Button title="Increment" onPress={() => this.props.incrementCounter()}></Button>
         <Button title="Decrement" onPress={() => this.props.decrementCounter()}></Button>
      </View>
    )
}
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>({
  incrementCounter: _ => dispatch({type:"INCREMENT_COUNTER"}),
  incrementCounter: _ => dispatch({type:"DECREMENT_COUNTER"}),
})
export default connect(state => ({ count: state.count }),mapDispatchToProps )(Test)
```

**reducers.js**

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    count: 1
}
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'COUNTER_INCREMENT': {
            return (Object.assign({}, { ...state, count: state.count + 1}))
        }
        case 'COUNTER_DECREMENT': {
            return Object.assign({},{ ...state,  count: state.count - 1 });
        }
        default: {
            return state;
        }
    }
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import { createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import Test from './src/screens/test';
import Screen2 from './src/screens/screen2';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducers from './reducers';

const store = createStore(reducers);

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  test: Test,
  screen2: Screen2
}, {
    headerMode: "none"
  });

export default class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppNavigator />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

**Expected behavior:**

It should connect to redux store and display `this.props.count` value

**P.S** :
This is just demonstration of my problem ,the actual code is similar to this demo

Comment: What is the name of the reducer? and you need to pass mapDispatchToProps  in connect

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally solve my problem by downgrading react-redux to 5.1.1 , the problem is that in react-redux 7.0.2 `connect()` method returns object but in `react-navigation 2.18.2` it assumed to be function I guess, so there is a type mismatch, therefore I have to downgrade react-redux to 5.1.1 which i used earlier in different project in which `connect()` method return function as expected by react-navigation.

PS: Its kinda weird that I configured a new project with the above question's environment setup and it works, but not work on existing project.

Comment: you re a life saver!

Comment: had to run `npm start -- --reset-cache` after downgrading

Answer (score 4):

I got this to work with Redux 7 and React Navigation 3 by wrapping the connected components you want to use in the Navigator like so:

```
import Component1 from "./Component1.js";
import Component2 from "./Component1.js";
import Component3 from "./Component1.js";
import Component4 from "./Component1.js";

const Component1Shell = () => {
  return <Component1 />;
};

const Component2Shell = () => {
  return <Component2 />;
};

const Component3Shell = () => {
  return <Component3/>;
};

const Component4Shell = () => {
  return <Component4/>;
};

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Page1: { screen: Component1Shell },
  Page2: { screen: Component2Shell },
  Page3: { screen: Component3Shell },
  Page4: { screen: Component4Shell }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still struggling:

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
     RouteNameOne: {
      screen:() => <Screen1/>
    },
    RouteNameTwo: {
      screen:() => <Screen2/>
    },
  },
  {
  initialRouteName: 'RouteNameOne',
  }
);
```

Try adding screen components to routes like this,it might work.

Answer (score 0):

using **mapStateToProps** might be the solution here,
you can use like

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
     return {
        count: state.count
     }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Test);
```

this can work i think so

Answer (score -1):

You have to use **mapStateToProps function** in your component
like this

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        state
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps() {
... your code to dispatch actions...
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(yourComponentName)
```